# Storing of deeply nested data structure in apache solr

Tags: java, solr, nested

We are developing a service discovery feature for a network management application. A same service is going to be deployed across all devices in the network with slight device specific variations. I want to develop a service discovery feature, that will discover service for all device and make a note of differences in configuration from one device to other device.

Service Structure is going to be something like this -

```
    ServiceConfig
BasicParam1 : BasicValue1
BasicParam2 : BasicValue2
ParentComplexParam1 : 
               BasicParam1 : BasicValue1
               BasicParam2 : BasicParam2
               ChildComplexParam1 : 
                             BasicParam1 : BasicValue1
                             InnerChildComplexParam1 : ...
```

ParentComplexParam2: ...

The service config is deeply nested. Though from device to device, as of now I want to find difference only for the outermost basic config and outermost param config.

We are planning to use apache solr for storing service structure. Is it possible to compare one entire document in solr with other document. I really don't need to search for any keyword. What I need is just whether service config structure on one device matches with service config structure on other device.

Hope I was able to formulate my question correctly. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not seem to be the best match for these conditions. You might be better off with graph-based approach, such as Neo4J.